# Specifying column to dataset

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, dataset

I did not know what exactly to write in the title. If you think its an incorrect title I'll change it.
Heres the problem. I am binding a dropdownlist to a dataset (a table) from where I need fields like Name, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Email, Country, etc... And I want to display these fields (values) on labels. Heres the complete code:

```
        public String GetSessionObject()
    {
        string strSession = "";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionEmail"] != null)
        {
            strSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionEmail"].ToString();

        }
        return strSession;
    }

    public DataSet BindDropDownListToAUserAddress()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT *, FirstName +' '+  LastName as FullName from AUserAddress where AUser_ID = (Select ID from AUser where Email='" + GetSessionObject() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds, "AUserAddress");
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }


  ddlName.DataSource = objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToAUserAddress().Tables["AUserAddress"];
            ddlName.DataTextField = "FullName";
            ddlName.DataBind();
            lblDisplayAddressLine1.Text = objBindDDL.BindDropDownListToAUserAddress().Tables["AUserAddress"].Columns.("AddressLine1").ToString();-----------????
```

This is where I am stuck. I need values from specific columns to go on specific labels. What option(s) do I have? Please guide....

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your question. Do you want to display the address of selected user of dropdown in Lable? then you should use `selectedIndexChanged` event. And what is DataValue field of your DDL?

Comment: see I'll tell you... I want to use the dataset created (middle code) to display text (Address, City, State, etc) on Labels... Its not on selected indexchanged, it should be there on pageload.

Comment: I have posted my answer take a look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understand your problem, for that you can do this

```
    // Get User's Details
   DataSet ds=BindDropDownListToAUserAddress();

   // Now from this dataset you can get the specific column like this
   if(ds!=null && ds.Tables.Count>0)
   {
     // I am assuming that your table contains single row of specific user
     string AddressLine1= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine1"].ToString();
     string AddressLine2= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine2"].ToString();
   }
```

Comment: yes, my table contains single row for one user. 
so after this, I do this: lblAddressLine1.Text = AddressLine1  rt?

Comment: Also, why Table [0].row[0].. I mean why zero??

Comment: Yes defiantly, even you can just write `lblAddressLine1.Text=ds.Tables[0].Row[0]["AddressLine1"].ToString();` No need to take into separate variable and then assign it Textbox text.

Comment: DataSet Contains multiple tables and tables contains multiple rows ho here `Table[0].Row[0]` means first row of  first table of dataset. and also we have only one table in dataset and our table has only one row that's why

Comment: but theres an error: System.Data.Datatable does not contain a definition for row !

Comment: ohh I have put typo so that is not row , it is actually `Rows`, take a look in my answer